# OWIN Startup: Entry point was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin, katana

The following `EntryPointNotFoundException` is being thrown in my OWIN `Startup` configuration upon executing `UseWebApi()`:

[image: EntryPointNotFoundException]

> An exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Http.Owin.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Entry point was not found.

Web API configuration:

```
public class WebApiConfig
{
    internal static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // IOC container
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

        // IOC resolution
        Resolver resolver = new Resolver();
        resolver.RegisterTypes(container);

        // Ignore any authentication which happens before the Web API pipeline.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();

        // API attribute routing
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // API formatters
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your `Startup` class decorated with the `OwinStartup` attribute?

Comment: @Amy: No. But it's in my project's "root" namespace.

Comment: Do you still get the exception if you add the attribute?  You can also add `<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="[NameSpace].Startup" />` to your app.config or web.config.

Comment: @Amy: Yes, I still get the exception.

Comment: Is your `IAppBuilder app` actually `null`?

Comment: @haim770: No, it's not `null`.

Comment: is it new, or existing one? Trying to reproduce your error, but it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was certainly quite odd.

I noticed that Visual Studio found conflicts between different versions of the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` assembly.

After allowing VS to fix the conflicts by adding the binding redirect (double clicking on the warning), every worked fine.

I don't understand how this could be related my problem.